# Почему не работает наложение двух background'ов?

Tags: css

У меня 2 background'а. 1 - обычная фотка, 2 - точечный(прикрепил). При CSS коде:

```
.bg {
background-image:url(img/bg1.jpg);
z-index:1;
}

.overlay {
background-image:url(img/overlay.png);
background-repeat:repeat;
position:fixed;
z-index:2;
}
```

Выскакивает только покрытие(.overlay) с z-index:2;

Но как сделать, чтобы она покрыла главный background. Она же точечная и вроде должны быть обе видны. А тут виден только тот, у которого z-index больше.

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6MKC5/ где проблема ?

Comment: [наверное здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/6MKC5/1/)...

Comment: значит все дело было в задании ширины и высоты. Странно

Comment: ну если фоновый элемент не виден, то он не виден совсем. что-бы вы "поверх" него не положили.

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте

```
 background-color: transparent;
```

к `.overlay` видимо он наследуется от других элементов... [как здесь примерно](http://jsfiddle.net/6MKC5/2/)